# Cannot Deploy Web Application to GlassFish 5/Payara 5 after adding Firebase SDK: "com/google/firebase/FirebaseOptions$Builder"

Tags: java, firebase, glassfish, firebase-admin, payara

I am trying to add the Google Firebase Admin SDK to my dynamic web application. I created a dynamic web application called **firebase** using eclipse and I converted it to a maven project using the popup menu and added the **firebase admin sdk** as a dependency. When I am deploying the web application to **Payara 5** it failes to deploy and I get the error:

```
 2018-05-07T15:27:18.478-0600|Severe: WebModule[/firebase]StandardWrapper.Throwable
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/firebase/FirebaseOptions$Builder
at services.FirebaseService.init(FirebaseService.java:28)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1515)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1323)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5494)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5739)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:609)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:956)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:939)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:684)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:2099)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1745)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:107)
at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:123)
at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:294)
at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:357)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.initialize(ApplicationLifecycle.java:538)
at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:514)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:549)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:545)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:544)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:575)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:567)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:566)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1475)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:111)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1857)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1733)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:564)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:251)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandlerBase.service(StaticHttpHandlerBase.java:190)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:516)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:213)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:242)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:539)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:593)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:573)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions$Builder
at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1659)
at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1505)
... 53 more
```

I am assuming this means that the firebase dependencies are not being copied over to my Payara Server or they are not being packaged into my .war file.

I'm not very familiar with Maven and I'm not sure what the correct way would be to get these dependencies on my Payara server. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was my scope for **com.google.firebase** in my **pom.xml** was set to provided. I deleted the scope tag (which I believe makes maven default to compiled for that dependency). I also used **run > maven install** in Eclipse. I then copied the .war file to my Payara Server instead of using **Run on server**